# T-Test or Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test?

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

So, for an experiment I analyzed behavioral data of two different treatment groups with $n = 30$ for each of two groups, so 60 subjects in total. I used a computational model to analyze the data and calculate a specific score that describes the motivation to obtain a specific reward.

This score is a continuous variable, but according to a Shapiro-Wilk test, the distribution of the data is non-normal. According to a two-sided Wilcoxon rank sum test, the difference between both groups is not significant ($p \approx .08$).
However, after performing an alternative (model-free) analysis by using logistic regression, I actually found a significant effect of treatment group on behavior.

Additionally, after performing a two sided t-test with the computational data, I also found a significant difference between both groups ($p \approx .04$).

Now the information that I have are quite contradictory. Some say that a sample size of 30 is sufficient to use a t-test, even if the data is not normally distributed. Other sources say that I still should use a u-test, even for "larger" sample sizes.

So I'm a bit confused. Of course, the results of the t-test fit with my hypothesis and the model-free findings. On the other hand, I want to use the "appropriate" test, not the one that confirms my hypothesis.

What do you think? Is my sample size big enough to use a t-test? Or should I go with the u-test, even though it contradicts the results of my alternative method?

**EDIT**: This is how the boxplot of my data looks like (adapted to the code below)
[image: Boxplot]

Comment: I am afraid that, by running so many tests in search of significance, you may have tainted your analysis. [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/882/) has a good cartoon along these lines.

Comment: Your two p-values, .04 and .08 really aren't that much different.  Both the t-test and the Wilcoxon test work fine at any sample size, though a practical minimum might be 4 or 5 observations per group for both tests. The Wilcoxon test doesn't really fix the problem of unequal variances; it works best when the the variances are equal but the distribution of the tails is higher than for the normal distribution. You might consider Welch's modification of a t-test, designed for unequal variances. You might describe the distribution of your values a little more.

Comment: The plot was made in R and R's `t.test` function defaults to Welch correction so chances are, that the t test result already was a Welch test result.

Comment: Depending of the units of the x-axis it may be that a difference between means of approx. 0.6 is not worth a discussion about its statistical significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not expect an accurate result from a two-sample
t test on samples that are sufficiently far from normal to
fail Shapiro-Wilk tests of normality. The P-value about 4%
would be just barely significant even if accurate.

If the two samples have approximately the same shape, a
Wilcoxon rank sum test might tell you whether population
*medians* are significantly different. However, this test
is not quite as powerful as a t test. In any case a P-value
about 8% is not impressive evidence for a significant difference between population locations.

@Dave has a good point that you have done too many tests
on the data. Cherry picking the smallest P-value of two
2-sample tests would be "P-hacking."

Consider the following fictitious data:

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = rexp(30, 1/10);  x2 = rexp(30, 1/15)
mean(x1); mean(x2)
[1] 9.384906
[1] 17.75834
```

Means are quite different. The issue is whether the difference
is statistically significant at, say, the 5% level. Boxplots show strongly right-skewed samples and apparently different dispersions.

```
x = c(x1,x2);  g = rep(1:2, each=30)
boxplot(x~g, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Normal probability plots are clearly not linear, so the
data should not be assumed normal. The Welch t test may or may not give useful results with sample sizes as large as $n_1=n_2 = 30.$

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(x1); qqline(x1, col="blue")
 qqnorm(x2); qqline(x2, col="blue")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

My first (and only) test would be a permutation test using the Welch t statistic as metric. This test does not assume that data are
normal, nor that the t statistic has a t distribution. It approximates the distribution of the t statistic for our data.  [We look at
P-values here because the Welch t test tends to have slightly
different degrees of freedom at each iteration.]

```
pv.obs = t.test(x~g)$p.val; pv.obs
[1] 0.02797518
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(x~sample(g))$p.val)
mean(pv <= pv.obs)
[1] 0.02633  # Sim. P-value of permutation text
```

So the permutation test finds a significant difference
at the 3% level.

Because the boxplots show different shapes (dispersions), I would stop there.

If you want to know what the pooled t test, and Wilcoxon rank sum test would have given, here are the results. But we have done a valid test already, so
these results are to satisfy curiosity, not as valid test results.

```
t.test(x1,x2, var.eq=T)$p.val # Pooled
[1] 0.02622975
wilcox.test(x1,x2)$p.val      # Wilcoxon SR
[1] 0.2358858
```

---

***Note:*** My fictitious right-skewed data for this Answer were sampled from exponential populations.
If you *know* that data are exponential, then there
is an exact test. See [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/558572/t-test-or-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test), where it is stated
that means of two independent exponential samples, each of size $n$ have $\frac{\bar X_1}{\bar X_2} \sim \mathsf{F}(2n,2n).$ So, for our data with $\bar X_2 > \bar X_1,$ the P-value of an exact 2-sided test is
$0.015.$

```
f = mean(x2)/mean(x1); f
[1] 1.892223
2*(1 - pf(f, 60, 60))
[1] 0.01470998
```

Comment: We don't actually care whether the samples are Normally distributed, only whether the sample mean (difference, in this case) is close to Normally distributed, because it is what is being tested.   For example, a sample mean from 12 Uniform variates was at one time close enough to Normally distributed to be used as a random number generator...  If I generate two sets of size 30 iid Exponential variates and take their difference, the t-statistic for testing that the mean $\neq 0$ (in my run of 100K experiments) rejected H0 5.023% of the time.

Comment: For normal data the sample mean $\bar X$ and the sample SD $S$ are independent. So, with non-normal data it is not quite enough to have $\bar X$ approx normal. The t statistic can fail to have a t dist'n because of correlation of it's numerator and denominator. A t test may have 5% rej. rate for exponentials with equal population means, yet have poor power because num. and denom. of t stat are highly correlated. Of course, the exact F-test behaves better. For my fictitious data Welch t rejected with P-val 0.027 and the exact test with P-val 0.015. Robustness of t is '"legendary," not ideal

Comment: @jbowman "We don't care whether the samples are Normally distributed, only whether the sample mean is close to Normally distributed" - not quite true. If you have a certain percentage of outliers but finite variance in the underlying distribution, the mean will be asymptotically normal about the distribution mean, but the distribution mean will be affected by outliers and therefore usually not be a sensible estimation target.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, I really appreciate your help.
So I basically adapted your code to my behavioral data. The boxplot with my data actually strongly resembles your boxplot with the fictitious data (right-skewed and different variance (~1.43 vs. ~2.6). However, according to the qq plot the non linearity is not as obvious as in your case (in fact, according to Shapiro Wilk, only the data of group 1 is non-linear, whereas the data of group 2 is actually linear).

I repeated the permutation test and found a significant difference at the 4% level

Comment: Only thing I'm curious about: What is your argumentation to prefer the permutation test over Wilcoxon rank sum test? Is it only because the rank sum test is less powerful?

Comment: There are fundamental problems with the way the issues were set up.  Testing for normality is bad statistical practice.  The Wilcoxon test works fine if the data are normality distributed.  Running multiple tests of a hypothesis is a no-no.  Logistic regression is not model-free but is a viable way to test group differences.

Comment: @ChristianHennig -If the actual data generating process isn't what we think it is, so we are modeling the wrong thing, we have a bigger problem than the appropriateness of the t-test!

Comment: @BruceET - oh, sure, if you can construct an exact test that's going to be better.  My point was with specific reference to the statement about the Normality of the data, but as you observe the robustness of the t-test at the null hypothesis is no guarantee of near-optimal power.